# Android Studio cannot resolve R in imported project?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-resources, android-studio

I'm trying the new Android Studio. I've exported a project from eclipse, using the build gradle option. I've then imported it in Android Studio. The R.java file under gen has a j in a little red circle on it. And in my source files, I get "cannot resolve symbol R" wherever I have a reference to a resource, e.g. "R.layout.account_list" etc.

I have never used Intellij before. Would appreciate any help as there obviously aren't many answer yet about Android Studio. Thanks!

Comment: Click on Build -> MAke Project

Comment: I had tried that but got an error saying "The specified gradle installation is not supported by this tooling API version". The gradle version being used, which I had to specify when importing the project, is in the "plugins" folder of the Android Studio installation folder. (It's version 1.6). Another issue is that when I quit and restart Android Studio, and it reopens the imported project, it says "The modules below have been removed from the gradle structure", and lists my main module (the name of my app).

Comment: I've tried using gradle 1.5 and it gets a bit further but still fails with this error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.ToolingModelBuilderRegistry

Comment: Maybe you should to use Build -> Rebuild project

Comment: Thanks, but that still causes the same errors. With gradle 1.6 the error is that the Gradle installation is not supported, with gradle 1.5 and 1.4 I get the classnotfoundexception. Maybe I'll try 1.3...

Comment: Please, star [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56855) if you stumbled upon this from the upgrade of Android Studio from 0.1.5 to 0.1.6

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. Press F4 into **Project Structure**, Check **SDKs** on left
2. Click **Modules** ---> **Source** Tab, check **gen** and **src** as sources

PS: The answer over a year old and the menus have changed.

Comment: Thank you very much, that has fixed the R not resolved problem. I will maybe ask another question about the gradle issues.

Comment: Is there a way to do this manually? After upgrading I got the message "We will provide a UI to configure project settings later. Until then, please manually edit your build.gradle file(s.)"  Also, for Mac it's command semicolon instead of F4.

Comment: This didn't do it for me (these folders are not present). I have the same problem, but the project was created from scratch in Android Studio, and it stopped working for no reason.

Comment: What do you mean by "Scheck SDKs on left"? Also, where can I find the gen and src folder?

Comment: As Tim said, don't get scared by the "We will provide a UI to configure project settings later" message. This solution still works in Android Studio 1.7.0.

Comment: When I go to Modules > Sources, I can see a gen folder but not a src folder. When I run 'Rebuild Project' my project compiles fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I can see a src folder but not a gen folder. What should I do?

Comment: Sorry to sound overly pedantic but those instructions are quite difficult to follow. What does F4 'into' Project Structure mean? You've said to check SDKs on the left but there's no checkbox. Under modules there is a 'Sources' tab and nowhere to 'check' gen and src and sources. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Horace you can into Project Structure from File menu. you can check gen or src use right key menu.

Comment: There is nothing like SDKs on the left.

Comment: This answer is no longer relevant due to the time difference. It's over a year old and the menus have changed.

Comment: @Axoren Yes, Android Studio 0.6.1 now.

Answer (score 29):

> File -> invalidate caches

then

> Restart application

Comment: Almost 2 hours of beating my head on my desk over this... so thanks!  But why doesn't a Clean or a Build solve this??? aargh.

Answer (score 13):

None of the answers on the web so far have helped. **Build > Make Project** did not work for me. For me it was as simple as choosing this other option (on Android Studio 1.3.1):

**Build > Make Module 'module name'**

Comment: Odd that "Make Project" doesn't do what this does. Just another voodoo magic operation that works because "it works".

Answer (score 7):

In my case I had an Activity file imported from Eclipse that had the line:

```
import android.R;
```

So all of my R classes were resolving to the SDK, as soon as I commented out that line everything compiled correctly to my package. I only noticed the issue when I was moving the project from my Mac to my Windows machine.

Comment: What did you do in the Mac/Windows case?

Comment: This is wrong because you cannot access R.layout.<your app layout> . Import  com.app.<projectname>.R instead (path can be different for your project).

Answer (score 4):

This issue starting occurring for me when I started working with build.gradle to incorporate the data necessary (signingConfigs) to build a signed .apk.  After what appeared to be a successful build from the command line, I discovered that going into any class using R.* that all R.* references were unresolved.

The answers here didn't help me.  I decided to re-import the project and it magically fixed the issue.  File/Import Project... and select the build.gradle file in my apps root folder.  I would love to know why re-import fixed this :)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably due to a failed resource build 
Once the issue is fixed, a mere `Build > Rebuild Project` will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Goto **File** -> **Settings** -> **Compiler** now check **use external build**

then rebuild project

Answer (score 2):

I've been frustrated on many occasions with this problem, especially when intergating a project library as part of another project. In the most recent occurrence of this plagued problem, my Android lib project was using a WebView. It turns out that Gradle builds the R.class file in a sub directory called "web" whose path does not have anything to do with my source code path. When I imported this, my problem was gone. What have I learned? In the future, simply do a file search for R.class and note the path where it is located. Then import the package into your code using that path. It really sucks that you have to manually perform this. Gradle should automatically import packages it generates.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue and I went  through lot of answer on stackoverflow. Then i found one solution which help me resolve this issue.

Check package name in AndroidManifest.xml file. I forgot to change it while copy pasting another project into new project.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the following, from [Crossle Song's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16588886/237838)

> 1. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> into Project Structure, Check SDKs on left
> 2. Click Modules ---> Source Tab, check gen and src as sources

Despite the message "We will provide a UI to configure project settings later....etc" this worked for me.

Comment: Please do not post `Me-Too` responses as answers.

Comment: Actually this was very helpful, as the "We will provide a UI later" message scared me off, and I almost gave up until I read Tim's answer.

Comment: When you copy content from somewhere else, please be sure to indicate where it came from. I've added that for you here.

Answer (score 1):

At first check if there is import android.R; in top of your class this happens when auto import in enable in android studio.

after that comment all lines of your code that you use R variable (you can comment entire class or ...)
then run application it regenerates R variable and you can uncomment your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me in IntelliJ (Not Studio), in addition to the replies presented above:

You need to attach an Android facet to an existing Android module. To do this, select the module from the module list in 'Module Settings', hit the '+' button on top and select 'Android'. See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-android-support.html.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to open project structure window. [by press command+; on mac ox s. i don't what's the key shortcut for other platforms. you should be able to find it under "File" menu.]
and click "Modules" under "Project settings" section, then your project is revealed, finally mark the generated R.java as Sources.

I am using Intellij idea 14.0 CE. 
The generated R.java is located at build/generated/source/r/debug/com/example/xxx

Really not easy to find for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the five steps below:

1. Step 1 ===>Delete(CTRL X) the additional tag(s) in XML manifest file.
2. Step 2 ===>Open Build-->Clean project.
3. Step 3 ===>Open XML manifest file and past the last additional tag(s) like:
   Tag Manifest file example:
   (`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>`)
4. Step 4 ===>Step 2 again.
5. Step 5 ===> Open Tool-->Android-->Sync project with 'Gradle'.

I have had the same problem but after all the steps it's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

On IntelliJ 14

Check if the generated sources are excluded. Usually in Project Structure -> [module] -> Paths -> Compiler output: "Inherit compile output path"

Answer (score 1):

check the build tools version in build.gradle(for module app). Then go to android sdk manager see if the version is installed if not install it or change the build tools version to the one which is installed like below.

```
    android {
          buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
          ..
          ..
          ..
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

just clean project and then sync your project with gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had file 'default.jpg' in drawable folder and for some reason every resource was not resolved. Fixed after deleting that file!

Answer (score 1):

You should check all your files if it don't have errors and again rebuild your project in:

- Build > Rebuild Project.

Or in:

- File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler

Check `use external build` and after rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

After you tried Clean and Rebuild without success, check your `res` folder for corrupted files.

In my case a corrupted `.png` file caused all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I solve that problem setting JAVA_HOME, CLASSPATH.

People sometimes skip JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH when setting Java_path.

So try to check Environment Variable.

CLASSPATH -> .;

JAVA_HOME -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk(version) or where Java installed

and then check the xml file which can have error(*Do not naming well-known things such as button,text etc*)

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers helped me!

My problem was not a problem! The program could compile completely and run on the device but the IDE has given me an annoying syntax error. It has underlined the lines of codes that included "R.".

The way that I could solve this issue:

I just added these three classes in "myapp/**gen**/com.example.app/" folder:

**BuildConfig**

```
package com.example.app;
public final class BuildConfig {
    public final static boolean DEBUG = true;
}
```

**Manifest**

```
package com.example.app;
public final class Manifest {
}
```

**R**

```
package com.example.app;
public final class R {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Linux, Android Studio 0.8.6 ) the following helps :

File > Project Structure > Modules > select main module > select its facet > Generated Sources

change value of "Directory for generated files:"

from

```
MY_PATH/.idea/gen
```

to

```
MY_PATH/gen
```

Without that code is compiled, apk is build and run successfully

but Android Studio editor highlights  mypackage.R.anything  as  "cannot resolve" in all sub-packages classes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got it fixed by deleting an extra library.

To do try this solution go to File > Project Structure (on a mac you can use the command "Apple ;")

Then select app on the left tab. Go to the dependencies tab and delete the extra library.

Comment: Could you give some more detail? For example, how to identify which library is the extra one.

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1373278/hoss
above worked for me.  I am reproducing it here because I cannot yet comment on hoss' post:

Remove `import android.R;`
from your activity file in question.

My setup:

Android Studio 1.2.2

Exported project from one Mac to Git (everything was working).  I then imported the project on another Mac from Git.  Thats when it stopped resolving the resource files.

I tried everything on this thread:

1. invalidating cache and restart
2. Delete .iml files and .idea folder and reimport project
3. Clean and Rebuild project

Nothing worked except removing `import android.R;` from my activity java file.

To avoid this issue in the future add `.idea` folder to your `.gitignore` file.  There is a nice plugin from git for gitignore in Android Studio.  Install this plugin and right click in `.idea > Add to .gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that "android.R.layout.account_list" was referenced instead of "R.layout.account_list".  Simply remove "android." can fix the problem.  Hope this help because sometimes you may overlook when you are too focusing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

I had to **Copy Reference** the R file; i.e. right click gen/<package>/R and Copy Reference. Then paste that over the R in your code where it fails to resolve.

That solved it for me (after trying everything else here). Still not sure why it worked to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. The package name was wrong in two of the following three files. I manually updated the package name and everything started working again.

gen/com/example/app/BuildConfig.java

gen/com/example/app/Manifest.java

gen/com/example/app/R.java

I'm not sure what caused them to change as I've never modified these files before.

Answer (score 0):

Had this error when importing project from Eclipse. The reason was some of the xml files had errors. Check ALL your XML files for errors. Including androidmanifest.xml, and values, themes, styles, layouts folders, etc. Warnings in xml are ok, but errors will generate this error.

Afterwards, do a Clean Project and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

For me, with Android Studio 1.5.1, the solution was to recreate the whole project with a slightly different name.

I think it didn't handle the app name "Kommentator_AS", because several places the package was named"Kommentator" instead.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue with intellij 2016.1 because I had set the generated sources to go to a directory that wasn't in the base project directory.

For example, in the Android facet, under "Generated Sources" I had:

`Directory for generated files: <project dir>/target/intellij-gen`

When I changed this to `<project dir>/gen` the problem went away.

Likewise when I then changed it to `<project dir>/gen2` the problem also went away - but I had to do a deep clean to get it to compile again by doing:

`rm -rf ~/.IdeaIC2016.1/system/compile-server/<project>_<hash>`

and deleting all the generated directories and `target` dir.