# Android Studio. Problems with R class

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I've upgraded to Android Studio 0.1.6 and cannot compile my project since.
I'm getting 81 errors in code wich was working perfectly fine with the previous version of the application. No code changes.

All of the errors related to the R class, examples:

```
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable string
location: class %mypackagename%.R
```

And

```
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable id
location: class %mypackagename%.R
```

I've tried to remove the content of the "gen" folder a few times, it get's regenerated, but it doesn't fix the problem.

I've looked for a solution all over the Internet, but can't find anybody with a similar problem. Some people having problems importing their projects to Android Studio, but my project was originality created in intellij idea and I keep working on it with Android Studio.

BTW, Intellij IDEA can compile and run project still, but I got used to Android Studio already.

I'm working on a MAC OS 10.8 if it makes any difference.

Your help is much appreciated.

UPDATE 1:
I've checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586899/android-studio-cannot-resolve-r-in-imported-project?rq=1), both gen and src selected as sources and I don't have "import android.r" anywhere in the code

Comment: No way you looked all over and didn't find anyone with the same problem, if you search StackOverflow with this term `android r class` you will get 4,188 results all of which are related. Also, there doesn't seem to be a single solution to this, every person has solved it with a different way, you just have to keep trying. And yes, I had this many times, and yes it just fixed itself! Can't explain how.

Comment: @LuckyMe, I'm talking about issue specific to me, when there is no issues with the xml files, when I've tried to rebuild the project and any other suggestion I found.

Comment: @Simon, instead of giving stupid comments, you could've suggest something new if you have so much experience with this problem. Doesn't look like you have any ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug in 0.1.6. Google has suggested turning off external builds in Preferences > compiler as a temporary fix

@simon this guy is supposed to be able to resolve a known bug in android studio that google hasn't been able to completely track down yet? If you're going to negatively comment on something like this please do your research first.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56843&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: What's fun is that I fixed this issue by turning in on :p By the way, it's still there in 0.1.7. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 4):

its a bug. But menu Build > Rebuild Project arranges everything.

Answer (score 1):

Error in your xml, correct and then:
Build-Rebuild Project.

precisely: it can be problem with rebuild sources and create R file.
Try to comment part of xml file, then press Rebuild project, then uncomment and rebuild, can help.

Comment: Thanks, but my issue was related to a bug in Android Studio 0.1.6, solved long time ago