# Android Studio 0.8.4 'R' cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

This question has been asked a bunch but in the threads I'm reading the main solution is either Rebuild project or quit and restart or some XML change. For me R disappeared once i executed a rebuild and at a time when i had made no changes to any xml.

I have had no problems, in this project, up until this point and have successfully compiled many times prior to this rebuild.

Any suggestions out there?

For ref:

-Project was not imported
-SDK manager is up to date
-Target and min are proper
-XML's were just fine and no changes have been made

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586899/android-studio-cannot-resolve-r-in-imported-project

Comment: "Clean the project and rebuild it" is a standard answer for every problem with R.java. From my own experience I can add: check your project's dependancies - I once imported one library twice and that was the source of my problems.

Comment: i'm going to poke around a few of those but most are related to a very old AS build or an imported build, or both. I guess I would like to know what is possibly happening from pre-rebuild to post that could have caused this to occur? 

The other times I've experienced this issue I was in a place where I either couldn't identify if I had or had not done something and could also scrap the project and start fresh.

Comment: Yeah the clean is absolutely not the fix at the moment, the rebuild, not clean however, is what got me into this mess. I have triple checked dependancies of the class files and there is no issue. This problem is across every class file that contains R.

Comment: Fixed another error I was having, independent of the R, tried just running the project and it compiled fine. The R is still red but is apparently not causing a problem? Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, the problem was actually syncing the gradle build files. So not clean project, not rebuild, but gradle sync. All good after that.