# Android app crashed , anyway to recover?

Tags: android

I am using android Studio. So after adding some images to xhdpi and hdpi folder I found no way to refresh the project just like you'd do in eclipse. And I found an almost similiar question in stackoverflow, where it was said to alter the gradle file. And when You do so, The IDE asks you to sync to work perfectly again . And I did sync. Now I got errors in all my Java files. What should I do ?

The errors in Java files are:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

telling cannot resolve R .

Also my another concern is , how do you refresh a project in Android Studio ? My aim is only to access the copied images in the respective folders

Comment: is the format of the image proper. usually they should be all lowercase with no space and only _ is allowed. Please check that

Comment: Paste your activity code.

Comment: Everything is fine with that! The problem never did occur then! It all started when i just added '//' and removed in build.gradle file. And when i did so, they asked me to sync , so that IDE would perfectly work again!

Comment: check for errors in your xml files..

Comment: There isn't any error in XML file!

Comment: @user3249477 more specific please ?

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16588886/3168859) helps you..

Comment: Add the code of your activity, namely your imports and activity prototype (`class Activity extends SomeActivity`).

Comment: "The problem never did occur then! It all started when i just added '//' and removed in build.gradle file" -- then edit your question, paste in your `build.gradle` file, and identify which line you commented out. If you want help with a problem in a file, you need to give us the file and point out the problem.

Comment: @Lal , Thank you bro, It worked! And how do you refresh a project in Android studio? or is there any better way to import images

Comment: copy paste is the only option i strongly believe..

Comment: and @shaheen can you mark my answer as accepted if i add one???

Comment: Why wouldn't I ?  You are a mallu as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See @Crossle 's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16588886/3168859)

It says,

> 1. Press F4 into **Project Structure**, Check **SDKs** on left
> 2. Click **Modules** ---> **Source** Tab, check **gen** and **src** as sources

and to import the images, the only way, or the best one, or the easiest one, which i believe is the **COPY & PASTE** Method..