# Gradle lost my R.java file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, r.java-file, crashlytics

I am migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio. My project has Crashlytics. Anyway, to add Crashlytics in the Android Studio version being migrated I followed the instructions and added

```
buildscript {
      repositories {
          maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }            
          maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'            
          classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
  }

  apply plugin: 'android'

  apply plugin: 'crashlytics'


  repositories {            
      maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
  }

  android {
      compileSdkVersion 18
      buildToolsVersion "18.0.0"

      defaultConfig {
          minSdkVersion 7
          targetSdkVersion 18
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')            
      compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
  }
```

After that, I could see Crashlytics but my `R.java` file could not be found. So, panicking, I did some `undo` to return my gradle file to the state it was before I made the changes for Crashlytics. But after I clean, then rebuild, then clean, my `R.java` is still not found. So now all my activity classes are screaming ERROR. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you try to clean / rebuild your project?

Comment: @poss Did you try reading the question?

Comment: R is generated automatically unless it finds errors in xml. So your clean and rebuild must have not worked or you ignored errors it raised.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio cannot resolve R in imported project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586899/android-studio-cannot-resolve-r-in-imported-project)

Comment: Check to see if there's any errors when re-syncing gradle / rebuilding project

Answer (score 0):

R.java is generated if all XML files have no errors. Check XML files.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this error and at the end i got tired, so i made a new app and transferred the activities and all the stuff(didn't take long), and it works now. Gradle build seems to have lot of bugs. Also as said you might wanna check your logcat.
Hope this helps.