# cannot resolve R symbol in androidStudio 1.2.2 version

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to import existing project in android studio, its showing me error can not resolve R.

I tried

- Rebuilding the project .
- Cleaning the project .
- Syncing with Gradle Files .
- Closing the Project, closing AS and relaunching / reopening .
- Double checking all support libraries are up to date in the SDK manager .
- delete iml file and .idea file .
- changing build version .
- changing plugin version .

Comment: Please explain your efforts, That will provide you a better answer!!

Comment: @MohabMohamed Yup, sure

Comment: Click on Build->Clean Project . You tried this?

Comment: Build->clean, rebuild the project, update the SDK, fix errors in xml file, all are solution for this.

Comment: In my experience, this is usually an error in one of your XML files.

Comment: yes i tried to clean

Comment: @Joshua explain please

Comment: what joshua mentioned is, check all the xml files in the project and make sure none of them is having an error.

Comment: @MohabMohamed First, make sure all of your own XML files(value, dimen, etc) have no error.

Second, in dependencies of build.gradle include the necessary libraries you used.

Comment: @Joshua no error also i copy-past dependencies  from new project to project with error and i get the same error

Comment: @MohabMohamed You do not need to copy from new project. It depends on what library you call. For example, I have "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'" because I use the action bar.

Copy-paste does not really help from new project. Check if you use any library from Google.

Comment: Try importing this after all imports and before 'public class..(..)' - import com.my.project.R;

Answer (score 0):

```
File -> invalidate caches
```

then

```
Restart application
```

[Android Studio cannot resolve R in imported project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586899/android-studio-cannot-resolve-r-in-imported-project)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586899/android-studio-cannot-resolve-r-in-imported-project go with site you may find a soultion