# R cannot be resolved to a variable-After Updating Android API 20 to new API 22 in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I Updated my **SDK API 20** to **API-22** in My Eclipse.

After Updating  i imported my  Project from Previous Workspace.

Each Java file Showing as a **R cannot be resolved to a variable**.

before Updating its Works fine for me.

Help me to solve this problem

Comment: Check your menifest. I thing it gets empty...

Comment: no manifest showing perfectly without error

Comment: Does any xml showing you error??? Any xml related to layout or theme or style.

Comment: http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/05/fixed-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-variable.html - followed this Link steps now no error. then cleaned the Project . Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to update the Android SDK Build-Tools to the latest version as well. Use the sdk manager to do so. Refer a similar question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586899/android-studio-cannot-resolve-r-in-imported-project)

Answer (score 1):

Clean your Project Once : Select Clean Option Under Project Tab.

Then Rebuild or Run Your Project.